# Cache custom function result between spreadsheet opens

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a Google spreadsheet that has it's data loaded using a custom function.
The custom function calls a REST API, transforms the data and displays it.

The problem is that every time I open the doc, the function is called and all the REST API calls go out.

I need to be able to manually trigger service calls to refresh data, and in between show the data from last time.

How can I best achieve that?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: I have searched the docs and the internet for the answer. Do you want a summary of how gas works? I was hoping someone did it and can point me in a direction. Usually people complain it does not get reloaded, I want it to stay the same

Comment: The guidelines doesn't requires a summary on how a service or any other thing works. The guidelines say "Search, and research ...and keep track " (on the question) " of what you find" .  By the way, add more details about the function as if it's a custom function or if it's called by an installable trigger.

Comment: the function is called in a cell as =myFunction(). The problem is it gets called every time the sheet is opened (by design) and I don't want that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of calling your function from a formula (custom function) call it from:

- The script editor
- A custom menu

## Explanation

At this time custom functions are recalculated when the spreadsheet is open and when any of its arguments changes its values. To run the function at will use the script editor play or debug buttons or a custom menu. Also you could use other triggers. Choose the one that best suit your needs.

If you still want to cache the result of calling the corresponding REST API use the [Class Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache).

## References

- [Overview of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/)