# This script does not populate sheet after parsing retrieved data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I hope this is well explained. First of all, sorry because my coding background is zero and I am just trying to "fix" a previously written script.

**Problem** The script  does not populate sheet after parsing retrieved data **if** the function is triggered by timer and the sheet is not open in my browser .

The script works OK if run it manually while sheet is open.

Problem details:
When I open the sheet the cells are stuck showing "Loading" and after a short time, data is written.

Expected behavior is to get the data written no matter if I don't open the sheet.

*Additional info*: This is how I manually run the function

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [
    {name: "Manual Push Report", functionName: "runTool"}
     ];
  sheet.addMenu("PageSpeed Menu", entries);
}
```

*Additional inf*o: I set the triggers with Google Apps Script GUI [See the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eghvF.png)

Before posting the script code, you can see how the cells look in the sheet:
[image: Cells in the sheet]

**Script code**

```
function runTool() {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Results");
var rows = activeSheet.getLastRow();


  for(var i=3; i <= rows; i++){
    var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var stuff = "=runCheck"

     if(workingCell != ""){
     activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setFormulaR1C1(stuff + "(R[0]C[-1])");

     }
     }    
}


// URL check //

function runCheck(Url) {

  var key = "XXXX Google PageSpeed API Key";
  var strategy = "desktop"

    var serviceUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + Url + "&key=" + key + "&strategy=" + strategy +"";

    var array = [];

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl);

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

        if ((content != null) && (content["lighthouseResult"] != null)) {

                if (content["captchaResult"]) {
                      var score = content["lighthouseResult"]["categories"]["performance"]["score"];

            } else {
                      var score = "An error occured";

            }
        }


    array.push([score,"complete"]);
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    return array;
}
}
```

You can try the code using the sheet below with a valid Pagespeed API key.

You only need to add a Trigger and wait for it's execution while the sheet is not open in your browser

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ED2u3bKpS0vaJdlCwsLOrZTp5U0_T8nZkmFHVluNvKY/copy

Comment: Can you share how are you calling the functions and how do you have the triggers set up?

Comment: Some info added to OP, thanks

Comment: I did not include new questions to the post, It was just a way to explain how I manually run the function and how I set the triggers.  The main question is still the same.   Or are you suggesting to mark this question as solved and then opening a new question about how to call UrlFetchApp properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your algorithm. Instead of using a *custom function* to call `UrlFetchApp`, do that call in the function called by a time-driven trigger.

You could keep your `runCheck` as is, just replace

```
activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setFormulaR1C1(stuff + "(R[0]C[-1])");
```

by

```
 activeSheet.getRange(i, 3, 1, 2).setValues(runCheck(url));
```

NOTE

Custom functions are calculated when the spreadsheet is opened and when its arguments changes while the spreadsheet is open.

Related

- [Cache custom function result between spreadsheet opens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40024872/1595451)

Comment: Thank you Ruben, that was pretty useful.  However I can't run your code because it can't find URL value (ReferenceError: Url is not defined at runTool(Metrics:14:58)

Comment: By the way, this is how I set the URLs to fetch.  https://i.imgur.com/mApARy2.png

Comment: Please add that image to the quesiton.

Comment: Image added to the question

Comment: Tonight I found the fix following your code. It works only by changing runCheck(url)  into runCheck(workingCell).   Thank you very much, question solved.